# position:fixed equivalent in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to keep an `ImageView`'s position fixed in a native android app, that is, it shouldn't move when a user scrolls.

In other words, I want the same effect what happens with css `position:fixed` in a web page.

The layout code is like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context=".ui.ProductDetailActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/product_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"/>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_model_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:text="@string/product_model_label"
            style="@style/ProductDetail"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_model"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dp"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I want the `TableLayout` to scroll over the image.

NOTE: My actual layout file has more table rows.

Comment: Don't put it inside of the scroll view.  Then it won't move.

Comment: Post you xml code then try to know how you can do this.

Comment: @Haresh, added code, please check!

Comment: i didn't find ScrollView any where in xml.

Comment: yes i know, but can i make the `TableLayout` scroll over the `ImageView` when the user tries to scroll ?  For example you can see Etsy app(screen which comes after clicking any product).

Answer (score 0):

add image view outside the scroll view . look at this example

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.sensor.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"
    android:padding="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test 1"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test 2"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
  </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>


  </LinearLayout>

  </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: But can i make it scroll over the `ImageView` somehow?

Comment: its parallax scroll view.. check the link [github](https://github.com/chrisjenx/ParallaxScrollView)[github](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll)

Comment: `parallaxscrollview` is dead according to the author. The same author has a new library called [paralloid](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid). So would be going with that. Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

use relative layout. .

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/product_image"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

you can add other parameters like alignParentLeft, center_Horizontal etc.

Comment: will this fix the `ImageView` on top and allow the `TableLayout` to scroll over it when the user scrolls?

Comment: it should. . . try it. .  do tell me the result.